# Capturar arquivo txt linha por linha e jogar em um txtbox

Tags: java, android

boa tarde preciso pegar o valor de um arquivo texto e escrever cada linha em um txtedit, o arquivo é gerado pelo código abaixo:

```
byte[] dados;


             File arquivo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/AperamApps/DBQ/DBQmestre/dados.txt");


             try {

             if (!arquivo.exists()) {
             //cria um arquivo (vazio)
             arquivo.createNewFile();
             }

             //caso seja um diretório, é possível listar seus arquivos e diretórios
             File[] arquivos = arquivo.listFiles();

             //escreve no arquivo
             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arquivo, true);

             BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                 bw.write("#1 "+as1);
                 bw.newLine();            
                 bw.write("#2 "+as2);
                 bw.newLine();     
                 bw.write("#3 "+as3);
                 bw.newLine();           
                 bw.write("#4 "+as4);
                 bw.newLine();
                 bw.write("#5 "+as5);
                 bw.newLine();
                 bw.write("#6 "+as6);
                 bw.newLine();
                 bw.write("#7 "+as7);
                 bw.newLine();
                 bw.write("#8 "+as8);
                 bw.newLine();
                 bw.write("#9 "+as9);
                 bw.newLine();
                 bw.write("#10 "+as10);
                 bw.newLine();

             bw.close();
             fw.close();              
             //faz a leitura do arquivo
             FileReader fr = new FileReader(arquivo);
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);              
             //equanto houver mais linhas
             while (br.ready()) {
             //lê a proxima linha
             String linha = br.readLine(); 
             //faz algo com a linha
             System.out.println(linha);
             }
             br.close();
             fr.close();   
             } catch (IOException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
             }
```

E aqui tenho o código que estou tentando utilizar para leitura do arquivo:

```
     BufferedReader br  = null;  
    try {  
        br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("/sdcard/AperamApps/DBQ/DBQmestre/dados.txt"));  
        for (String linha = br.readLine(); linha != null; linha = br.readLine()){

            while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(linha);

                br.readLine();

                txtcoluna1.setText(linha);
            }



        }  
 br.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

O código até consegue ler, porem ele exibe sempre a última linha do arquivo texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está a atribuir o conteúdo de cada linha ao TextView dentro do ciclo `while`. De cada vez que é feita uma nova passagem a nova atribuição repõem o que a anterior tinha atribuído.

Uma solução passa por usar um [StringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) para ir construindo o texto e no final da leitura atribuir o resultado ao TextView.

Antes de iniciar a leitura, fora dos *loops*:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Durante a leitura, dentro do *loop*:

```
sb.append(linha));
```

No final da leitura, fora dos *loops*:

```
txtcoluna1.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Boa tarde, obrigado pela resposta, corrigi o código porém continuo com o mesmo problema;
             
             BufferedReader br  = null;  
    try {  
        br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("/sdcard/AperamApps/DBQ/DBQmestre/dados.txt"));  
        for (String linha = br.readLine(); linha != null; linha = br.readLine()){
         
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append(linha);
        txtcoluna1.setText(sb.toString());
        tch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace(); }

Comment: O `txtcoluna1.setText(sb.toString());` tem que que ser colocado fora dos loops, no fim.

Comment: Ok, agora o txtcoluna1 exibe todo o arquivo de texto, começando do item 1 ao 10.
Como eu faço para filtrar esses dados, por exemplo: Minha aplicação possui 10 txtedit (txtcoluna1, txtcoluna2, txtcoluna3...txtconlunaN), e o arquivo texto possui 10 linhas, como coloco a linha 1 para ser exibida no txtcoluna1, a linha 2 no txtcoluna2 ?

Comment: Use um [ArrayList<String>](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) em vez do StringBuilder.